# What is wrong with my question

Tags: discussion

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/107934/pc2-lab-build-cost

I put in the comments why I wrote the words, which lbh, were meaningless, my question is very related to biology - specifically the study of such.

This is meant to be a scientific community, what is wrong with my question?

The original question has been deleted in the meantime, but here's a copy:

> Does anybody have a ballpark figure of how much money a small PC2 laboratory would cost to make?

Comment: this is an international site and the cost will be wildly variable depending on where you live,and you need to give a lot more information about what you are going to study in the lab.

Comment: this is what this question is about https://www.utas.edu.au/research-admin/research-integrity-and-ethics-unit-rieu/biosafety/certified-facilities

Comment: @trondhansen yes, much more information is needed before the question can be answered, but the fact remains that the question is off-topic, and included an immature, offensive attempt at bypassing the question quality filter as well. Brian has an excellent answer below.

Answer (score 11):

> a small PC2 laboratory

We have no idea what this is. What's "small"? What is "PC2"? The "Programming Contest Control System"? Proprotein convertase 2? DDR2 RAM? A polycomb-group protein?

Assuming you refer to some sort of protein, what are you doing with it? Producing it? Mutating it? Measuring pre-existing variation in a human or livestock population? Cloning a version of the protein from killer whales into human embryos and raising the hybrids? The question is not meaningful as stated.

Further, our site welcomes:

https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

- general questions about biological concepts
- questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions
- questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory

The economics of setting up a lab of any sort are not included in those bullet points. There is too much variation to be meaningful, as costs will be completely different in different places and according to exactly what each lab is doing. No two labs will be the same, so no two costs will be the same, so no answer is correct. If one was able to somehow make a correct answer, it would quickly become wrong as costs for everything from labor to technical equipment to daily use reagents fluctuates over time unpredictably, sometimes in different directions.

Lastly, your question contained some useless phrase pertaining neither to your question nor to Stack Exchange. This phrase is a joke from an old movie that is highly offensive to members of a particular religion. Whatever satirical value that phrase may have had in the movie, it is entirely lost when reproduced out of context the way you have. This is clearly against the [Code of Conduct](https://biology.stackexchange.com/conduct) that our site operates on and the reason your question was deleted rather than merely closed. Any of the good faith we assume when a new user visits our site evaporates when you include content like this.

It seems you've done this further as a response to some automatic systems meant to prevent posting junk questions. Rather than think about how you could possibly improve your question, you added some useless junk to bypass a filter? Can you see how rude that is? You want volunteers to spend their time on something you want to know to help you out, but you're unwilling to put any effort into the presentation at all? That is highly unprofessional behavior and you won't find any tolerance for it across StackExchange.